# Locally enclose a code block in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

In Java you can do the following to locally scope variables within a method:

```
public void blah() {
    {
        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;
    }
    {
        int a = 3;
        int b = 4;
    }
}
```

I don't even know what the name for this technique is, I've only needed to use it once or twice. In my current situation, this may really come in handy with this SQL project.

Is this even possible in SQL?

---

I'm using MS SQL Server...
To give more context to the situation:

We have several sql scripts stored as files which help perform various operations on a database. These scripts are fairly large and were designed to be run independently. Sometimes, we need to run several of these scripts together and deliver in a single file.

Since most of these script have common variables we run into a conflict when joining these scripts together. Of course, it is easy to move all variable declaration to the beginning of the file, but the goal is to have this process automated.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Oracle? MySQL? Postgresql?

Comment: If you have some SQL that you'd like to improve, or even just a SQL-like pseudocode, that might be a better example.

Comment: Thanks, I added a bit more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL is a declarative language (i.e. focuses on the 'whats' and not the 'hows'). Hence its definition (ansi) does not contain procedurals and blocks.

Most vendor implementations fill this void by embedding their own procedural language - TSQL in case of Microsoft, PL/SQL in case of Oracle etc. (Not sure of Mysql and SQLlite etc) - and even they dont do an exact feature match with Java (No anonymous codeblocks).

Each SQL operation works on a set, and returns a set.

Thus "mytable" is a set, "select from mytable" is a set , and "select from (select from mytable) " is a set.

So its kind of not possible to drill down into a lower level of granularity, perhaps "columns" or pseudo columns are the 'variables'

Oracle defines a "select from dual" operation to guarantee a 'loop' of 1 (i.e. a select statement that returns exactly 1 row)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL variable declarations must come at the beginning of the subroutine/stored procedure, like a C function's variables must be.

Comment: C fully allows a { } block, inside a function, to have its own variable declarations -- the block's variables have the block's lifetime and may shadow outer-block ones (in Java, the latter is forbidden, so the OP's code doesn't actually compile in Java).

Answer (score 0):

Trying to compile the Java code example you give (wrapped in a `class helo`) ## Heading ##produces:

```
$ javac helo.java 
helo.java:7: a is already defined in blah()
        int a = 3;
            ^
helo.java:8: b is already defined in blah()
        int b = 4;
            ^
2 errors
```

So, no, you *cannot* do that in Java (C, yes; C++, yes; Java, no).

SQL per se doesn't have lexical scoping, although some stored-procedure dialects embedded in relational DBs surely may (but it's hard to help w/o knowing the exact dialect). In SQL proper, you qualify otherwise-homonymous fields with `tablename.` prefixes.

Comment: I think he may have just gave a bad example

Comment: Yes, bad example. Although, I used this some days ago and it worked, but maybe I used unique variable names within the block. Hm...

Comment: Point is, you _cannot_ locally scope homonymous variables within a block in Java (though you can in other languages) -- nor in SQL per se either (though some procedure dialects may differ, the OP needs to specify which one[s] he cares about). Java deliberately forbids this because its designers considered it bad practice even though it was common in C and C++ (I agree with Java's designers on this specific point, FWIW).

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can't scope in blocks. As long as DECLARE is before SET you're OK.
The DECLAREs don't have to be at the start of the batch or code either

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @a int
END
BEGIN
    SET @a = 1
END
```

IIRC, the same applies to Sybase too.